# Not able to install Linux::Inotify2 on freeBSD

Tags: linux, perl, freebsd, cpan, inotify

I am trying to install Inotify2 on freeBSD, but test step throws error.

`cpan install Linux::Inotify2`

It throws the following error:

```
root@freebsd12sabin:~/.cpan/build/Linux-Inotify2-2.1-6 # make test
"/usr/local/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Inotify2.bs blib/arch/auto/Linux/Inotify2/Inotify2.bs 644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/local/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00_load.t ..... Can't load '/root/.cpan/build/Linux-Inotify2-2.1-6/blib/arch/auto/Linux/Inotify2/Inotify2.so' for module Linux::Inotify2: /root/.cpan/build/Linux-Inotify2-2.1-6/blib/arch/auto/Linux/Inotify2/Inotify2.so: Undefined symbol "inotify_init" at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.30/mach/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
 at /root/.cpan/build/Linux-Inotify2-2.1-6/blib/lib/Linux/Inotify2.pm line 97.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/Linux-Inotify2-2.1-6/blib/lib/Linux/Inotify2.pm line 97.
```

Is there anyway I can proceed?

Comment: cpan -T Linux::Inotify2 installs Inotify2, but throws error: Undefined symbol "inotify_init"

Answer (score 2):

You need to use alternatives that work on the OS.

- [File::ChangeNotify](http://p3rl.org/File::ChangeNotify) with [IO::KQueue](http://p3rl.org/IO::KQueue)
- [gamin](http://enwp.org/gamin) and [Sys::Gamin](http://p3rl.org/Sys::Gamin)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is `devel/libinotify` library, which implements inotify interface on FreeBSD via `kevent` API. So, there might be possible to build this extension.

If you got to `Undefined symbol "inotify_init"` stage, the only thing left is to install `libinotify` package and then add proper `-l` flag to build command line. I'm not familiar with Perl build system, so I can't advise on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Inotify is a Linux specific API. You can't use it on FreeBSD (or any other OS not using a Linux kernel) because that kernel doesn't provide those syscalls.